# Cannot log in alts in consoleclient

Tags: command-line, bash, minecraft, gnu-screen

So I am on a minecraft server, I want alt-accounts afking via a console client.

So instead of running this 35 times.

```
screen -d -m mono MinecraftClient.exe (username) (password) (Server-IP)
```

I came up with an idea of getting some kind of script running.

which lead to this:

```
screen -d -m mono MinecraftClient.exe (user) (password) (IP)
sleep 10
screen -d -m mono MinecraftClient.exe (user) (password) (IP)
```

This for 35 clients.

EDIT:

```
screen -dmS 'Alt1' bash -c "mono MinecraftClient.exe (user) (password) (IP)
sleep 10
screen -dmS 'Alt2' bash -c "mono MinecraftClient.exe (user) (password) (IP)
```

UPDATE:

Comment: Could you explain a little more, I can't really get what you want me to try?

Comment: Edited post and question.

Comment: VTC as irreproducible because the OP cancelled the VPS which was in trial mode.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with your screen syntax, try

```
screen -dmS 'NAMEofSCREEN' bash -c "mono MinecraftClient.exe (user) (password) (IP)"
```

This would be the correct syntax for giving commands to screen, you can omit the `-S`and `NAMEofSCREEN` but that might make it easier for you to find the screens you are looking for.

Comment: But I found out, while that "_" was flashing, it was actually running the script. But out of 35 alts, 2 actuallly logged in..

Without the -d -m I will open a screen for each alt, and the terminal is attached to that screen right?, with -d -m i open it in de-attached mode (won't that cause problems?)

Comment: "`-d`" is for detach, correct  `-m` is just for "safety" as it will guarantee a new screen session.  Its not a problem, as you can attach each screen individually: to see all your screens `screen -list`and to attach to one `screen -r <screenname>`. Detach is done with `Ctrl-A` followed by `D`.  Best to uses `" command"` with screen, otherwise it might disregard your options (user, ip, password). Regarding the issue that not everything worked with the minecraft server.. dunno, mybe increase the sleep timer ? I cannot help you with that...

Comment: Just ran that command, doesn't open up one single screen.

Comment: sorry, I forgot the `bash -c`, I will edit my answer

Comment: Also, just FYI: the screen terminates if your minecraft client terminates with `exit 0`. To keep the screen open/busy you can add `; exec bash` inside the `" "`.

Comment: Does open one screen now. It now says 

Incorrect password

Is this because of the thing you said "Detach is done with Ctrl-A followed by D. Best to uses " command" with screen, otherwise it might disregard your options (user, ip, password).."

Logging in takes around 1 to 2seconds, I think it can't login that quick as the terminal is way quicker than that

Comment: Are you using the options "`-dm`" otheriwse you will only get ONE screen. I just told you how attach/detach works in `screen`. Maybe edit your answer and post your whole script ?

Comment: Edited post, with my script

Comment: If this is the complete script then you forgot the closing double quotes `"` and okay, I think you should use a different name for each `screen`, like "Alt1" , "Alt2", "Alt3" - otherwise `screen` will number them for you, which can be confusing.  Also, regarding your comments  about "closing the screen" - each line in your script opens a new screen session. these sessions don't close unless mono with the mincraftclient.exe closes, or you close them

Comment: But when I copy that command and run it by myself, it will log in. In script it says invalid password, why would it?

Comment: And about the Alt1, Alt2, Alt3, thats a mistake in the post not in the script itself

Comment: the "invalid password" .... you added the closing quotes `"`, right ? and you removed the brackets `( )` (sorry about this question) ?

Comment: Where would I put the ";exec bash"

Comment: like this `screen -dmS 'Alt1' bash -c "mono MinecraftClient.exe username password IP; exec bash"`  - don't forget the double-quotes

Comment: Typing that all by myself in terminal opens up a screen (Detached). When I run a script it doesnt. The password is wrong when typing command in terminal

Comment: okay, you failed to post the complete script - the "shebang" is missing for example. Maybe I can help you then, otherwise I'm starting to run out of ideas.

Comment: Where in the line would I put "shebang"

Answer (score 0):

As it kept failing, then Got a succesfull script working (it was logging in 2 out of 2 alts in)

Then tried running the same command for different alts. 
It kept saying invalid password. So I Cancelled the VPS ( i was in trial mode)

I do appreaciate your help Robert. Thanks alot.

Whoever can, you are free to close this